# How do I specify the timezone and date object format on moment correct such that I do not get Invalid date and a moment is deprecated warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to set the date format and timezone and then when I try to format moment to extract the date it just returns Invalid date.

When I do it this way I do not get moment is deprecated.

```
let data = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM').tz(TIMEZONE); //moment('2014-06-01 12:00:00Z').tz(TIMEZONE); // TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'
console.log(data.format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
let value = inventoryBase.lastUpdated + SPACE + data.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' at ' + data.format('LT') + SPACE + moment.tz([2012, 0], TIMEZONE).zoneAbbr();
value = value + ' by ' + lastUpdated.editedBy;
```

But the output of value is incorrect:

```
Last updated Invalid date at Invalid date EST by System
```

When I do it this way I get moment is deprecated.

```
let data = moment(date).tz(TIMEZONE); //moment('2014-06-01 12:00:00Z').tz(TIMEZONE);
let value = inventoryBase.lastUpdated + SPACE + data.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' at ' + data.format('LT') + SPACE + moment.tz([2012, 0], TIMEZONE).zoneAbbr();
value = value + ' by ' + lastUpdated.editedBy;
```

But the output of value is correct:

```
Last updated 05/01/2019 at 3:59 AM EST by System
```

Moment is deprecated error:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO 
format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable 
across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are 
discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer 
to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

Comment: Why `+ ' at ' +` and not `+ SPACE + 'at' + SPACE +`?

Comment: Yea I am going through and refactoring this. I added the SPACE. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const data = moment.tz(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ', TIMEZONE);
const value = `${inventoryBase.lastUpdated} ${data.format('L [at] LT zz')} by ${lastUpdated.editedBy}`;
```

A few other points:

- In your original code, it didn't work correctly because your format string didn't match the format of the data.  `MM` is months, while `mm` is minutes, and you didn't include seconds.
- In your second attempt, you got the deprecation warning because you provided data in a format that isn't in [the list of known supported strings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).
- You were taking the zone abbreviation for an arbitrary date instead of the one in question.  Time zone abbreviations vary by date, so it's better to get it from the same moment you're working with.
- It's not good to mix tokenized formats (`MM/DD/YYYY`) and locale-aware formats (`LT`) in the same output string.  I used `L` instead, as it gets the date format for the locale you're working with.
- Because you have a `Z` in your data, it will always be treated as UTC.  Thus you can skip right to parsing it with `moment.tz`.  If you didn't have the `Z`, then you would go through `moment.utc(data, format).tz(timezone)` instead.
- I used JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in my answer because I think they are cleaner than concatenation for cases like this.